# Kendo grid :Need of Two horizontal scrollbars one at below the header field and another one at the bottom of the grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Am working on kendo-UI.
I have an requirement to have two horizontal scroll bars, one at below the header fields and another one at the bottom.

I have seen some samples, which have two horizontal scroll bars, one at above the grid and another one at the bottom.That wont suits my requirement.

Do help, because I tried alot and I couldnt come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper div the Header and footer in your grid template.

```
<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div class="wrapper1">      
    </div>
       Grid template content header, body and footer 
    <div class="wrapper2">
    </div>
</script>
```

then

```
$(".wrapper1").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper2")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
});
$(".wrapper2").scroll(function(){
    $(".wrapper1")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper2").scrollLeft());
});
```

If you would like the scroll to be in the header or footer you need to use the header and footer templates respectively.
Here is the api reference to the header templates. [kendo grid header templates](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.headertemplate)

Comment: Thanks @Carlos for you help, your code adds the scrollbar at the top of kendo grid and at the bottom, but I want the scroll bar below the header field of the kendo grid and at the bottom

Comment: Kendo provides also a Header Template instead of the grid template. Theoretically you can apply the same thing to the header template and the footer template.